# When do we have orthogonal bases in a vector space equipped with a skew-symmetric form?

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, vector-spaces, bilinear-form, skew-symmetric-matrices

Suppose we have a vector space $V$ over some field $\mathbb F$ together with a skew-symmetric form $\langle\space ,\space \rangle$, i.e., $\langle\space ,\space \rangle$ is bilinear and $\langle v,v\rangle=0$ for all $v\in V$. Then when do we have an orthogonal bases?

Unlike the symmetric form over a field with $\mathbb F$ with $\text{char}(\mathbb F)\ne 2$ or Hermitian form over the complex field $\mathbb C$, $\langle v,v\rangle=0$ for all $v\in V$, so we can not find orthogonal bases like what we did for the above two cases.

Are there classifications for vector spaces equipped with a skew-symmetric form such that there exist orthogonal bases? Thank you!

Comment: Note: the condition $\langle v, v \rangle = 0$ is usually called "alternating". This is only equivalent to skew-symmetry if $\operatorname{char}(\mathbb{F}) \neq 2$.

Comment: What do you mean by "orthogonal" here? Do you mean that if $i \neq j$ then $\langle v_i, v_j \rangle = 0$? In that case $\langle v_i, v_j \rangle = 0$ for all $i, j$ so the form must be identically zero. The correct thing to ask for (in the nondegenerate case) is a symplectic basis: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symplectic_basis

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To expand on Qiaochu's comment, suppose we have a basis $(v_1, \dots, v_k)$ for $V$ such that $\langle v_i, v_j \rangle = 0$ for all $i \neq j$. Well, for $i = j$, we also have $\langle v_i, v_j \rangle = 0$ by the alternating hypothesis. Now, in this basis, the matrix representing the bilinear form is the zero matrix! Thus, we cannot have such a basis unless the bilinear form is $0$.

Edit: Qiaochu edited his comment with more details, so nevermind :)